# How to make dropdown on top of accordion

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-accordion module to show like this
[image]

Now when I click on details dropdown button the view is 
[image]

The accordion adjusts its height to the dropdown. But I want the dropdown to be on top of accordion and not inside.

Comment: sorry...maybe it's just me...but I can't see any difference between the two screenshots..furthermore...can you provide the code you wrote?

Comment: @FabioEnne The problem is in the second view if you see when the drop-down is opened, the accordion adjusts its height such that the dropdown is inside the accordion body. I need it to be on top of the accordion body.

Comment: @FabioEnne sorry I uploaded wrong image. I suppose now it should be clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not using [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) but in some similar libraries you can use an `appendToBody` option to solve such errors.

For ngx-bootstrap you can find an example [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#container):

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown container="body">
  <button id="button-container" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
          aria-controls="dropdown-container">
    Dropdown on Body <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="dropdown-container" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
      role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-container">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Key part is to add `container="body"` to your dropdown.